# Vuejs Send row data to parent component

Tags: vue.js, antd

I'm trying to call a certain function when I select a row from the ant-design-vue table. So far I have this in my code:

```
<script>
  const rowSelection = {
     onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
       console.log(`selectedRowKeys: ${selectedRowKeys}`, 'selectedRows: ', selectedRows);
     },
     onSelect: (record, selected, selectedRows) => {
       console.log(record, selected, selectedRows);
     },
     onSelectAll: (selected, selectedRows, changeRows) => {
       console.log(selected, selectedRows, changeRows);
     },
  };
</script>
```

This is from the ant-desing-vue documentation. I want to call a method inside the onSelect function which will emit a selected event to the parent component like this:

```
<script>
   ...
   onSelect: (record, selected, selectedRows) => {
     console.log(record, selected, selectedRows);
     this.handleEvent(record);
   },
   ...
   export default {
      methods: {
         handleEvent(record) {
             this.$emit('selected', record);
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

But this obviously doesn't work because the this keyword doesn't have the same reference in the rowSelection variable. So what could be an alternative to this, in order to send the data from the row to the parent component?

**Edit: here's the template with the table:**

```
<a-table
   v-if="this.item.toString() === '1'"
   :columns="columns"
   :row-key="record => record.guid"
   :data-source="filteredList"
   :pagination="pagination"
   :row-selection="rowSelection"
>
</a-table>
```

Comment: where is said docs? how are you using rowSelection?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: here is the docs https://www.antdv.com/components/table/ I took the code from  the selection & operation table

Comment: make rowSelection a computed prop like the docs shows, then `this` would be vues

Comment: But how exactly can I make it a computed  prop because I have 3 functions in it

Comment: `computed: {rowSelection}` or physically move the object there is no requirement for it to be outside.